# C++ OpenCV 2.4.11: List all cameras

Tags: c++, opencv, webcam, video-capture

I want to list all connected webcams (USB-webcams and internal webcams), using C++, OpenCV 2.4.11, Windows 8.1 and Qt Creator 3.4.2.
For me it is enough to get the number of accessible webcams in the following way:

```
VideoCapture videoCapture(0); // Will access my internal laptop webcam.
VideoCapture videoCapture(1); // Will access the first connected usb webcam.
```

Here is my code:

```
// Following procedure detects, how many webcams are accessible from 0 on upwards.
numberOfDevices = 0;
bool noError = true;

while (noError)
{
    try
    {
        // Check if camera is available.
        VideoCapture videoCapture(numberOfDevices); // Will crash if not available, hence try/catch.

        // ...
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        noError = false;
    }

    // If above call worked, we have found another camera.
    numberOfDevices++;
}
```

The code in the try-block works if I have activated my internal webcam. The call fails when I deactivate the internal camera in the hardware manager (and no other camera is attached to my laptop) with the following error message (debug mode):

> ```
> Exception Triggered
> ---------------------------
> The inferior stopped because it triggered an exception.<p>Stopped in thread 0 by: 
> Exception at 0x7ff8533d9090, code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at: 0x0, flags=0x0 (first chance).
> ```

and the following 2 build problems:

> ```
> Exception at 0x7ff871af8b9c, code: 0xa1a01db1: , flags=0x0 (first chance)
>
> Exception at 0x7ff8533d9090, code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at: 0x0, flags=0x0 (first chance)
> ```

How can I fetch the occuring error? As you see, try/catch does not work.

Or is there a method where I can access all available webcams in OpenCV without such a dirty loop?

Comment: I didn't observe crashes on Windows, when doing something very similar...

Comment: ok, this seems to depend on the installed device drivers. I had no problems testing inexistent devices by just trying to open them until I installed a GigE camera...

Comment: There is a similar thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322939/how-to-count-cameras-in-opencv-2-3). The commenters had different results. :/

Comment: I would encourage you to use VideoInput library (used by openCV internally anyways): https://github.com/ofTheo/videoInput

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is still no functionality related to camera count in **OpenCV** at the current moment (**3.0.0** version) - see [corresponding ticket](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/4269).

Proper camera handling seems like an **OpenCV** internal problem (for example, described [here](http://code.opencv.org/issues/2528) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179884/opencv-access-violation-reading-location-somewhere-in-highgui-lib)). Usually it appears in capture code after physically disabling camera while it is still opened in **OpenCV** (when we try to read destroyed file descriptor).

Generally you can even implement your own handler for access violations (please look into [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457577/catching-access-violation-exceptions)), but it's really dirty trick.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I search for something else so that I can avoid above dirty trick. I will update this topic if I find a sufficient solution.

Answer (score 4):

I created this C++ class that allows enumerating devices (including the ID) to be used inside OpenCV. It is hosted on GitHub.

https://github.com/studiosi/OpenCVDeviceEnumerator

The idea is to use DirectShow to get all the devices that have the category with GUID CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory, and then, through an enumerator, you get in which order they appear on the system, which is the ID you need to open them on OpenCV by creating a VideoCapture object (by using the constructor that receives the ID, which would be the index of the device on the enumeration). Obviously, this approach only works on Windows.

Comment: Please consider to explain the solution the original question, instead of linking to other classes and resources.

Comment: Added explanation. Still recommend to see the code.

Comment: This used to work in v3, but v4, seems like the order doesn't match up. Any one got any idea how to map the index to the camera name?

Comment: I don't see a reason that the OpenCV version interferes with device enumeration, what do you mean?