# Is there a platform independent way to list video input devices

Tags: java, opencv

Before opening doing a capture by creating a VideoCapture object I want to display a list of available devices to select from. I believe this can be done in Windows using DirectShow and in Linux by checking the /dev/video* entries.

But I am wondering if there is any platform independent way I can get this list?

NOTE. I know I can enumerate the devices using VideoCapture.open and checking isOpen but I want to be able to display a meaningful name also and I don't think VideoCapture gives me that?

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.codepool.biz/multiple-camera-opencv-python-windows.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044539/listing-available-devices-in-python-opencv

Answer (score 1):

I understand that **available devices** means **cameras** connected to your computer.

- Firstly, to be able to use `VideoCapture` with a camera; camera shouldn't have a driver. Generally, `VideoCapture` is available to use with simple cameras such as webcams, some usb cameras etc.
- OpenCV doesn't have a property to count or list the available cameras which are connected. You can also check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197825/c-opencv-2-4-11-list-all-cameras).
- Just for counting cameras, you can also use a brute way like this:

Example:

```
VideoCapture cap;
    int device_counts = 0;
    while ( true ) {
        if ( !cap.open(device_counts++) ) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

- But in my opinion, the best solution is that using a framework to achieve that. For example [Qt Creator](https://www.qt.io/).

Comment: I meant to say I want to be able to display a meaningful name to the user and don't think the above approach allows that. Have updated the question

Comment: Using a framework will give you a directly the device name