# Changing camera default from depth to rgb with OpenCV (intel RealSense)

Tags: python, opencv, realsense

W10, Python 3.6, OpenCV 4.3.0, Spyder 4.0.1

I'm using the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34588758/3595907) to take snap shots from my *Intel(R) Realsense(TM) 3D Camera (Front F200)*.

The problem is that it is defaulting to *Depth* mode and not *RGB*.

Is there a way of switching between the two modes from my code?

Comment: Maybe you can change input, instead of cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0), can be cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1) or 2,3 depending on device.

Comment: @dpetrini I just get "failed to grab frame" as there physically is only one camera attached

Comment: In this case you need to check real Sense camera API documentation I guess, to change the default video stream

Comment: Maybe this site can help: https://dev.intelrealsense.com/docs/opencv-wrapper .

Comment: Intel Realsense has their own driver with SDK. You can not call the cameras which has own driver like the webcam, or usb cameras. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61510571/is-there-a-platform-independent-way-to-list-video-input-devices/61520579#61520579)